# How to install pear image graph in ubuntu 16 with offline installation

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, pear, image-graphviz

I have tried install pear image graph online.

```
sudo pear install image_graph
```

but now I can reach the site, it show this message:

```
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/image_graph"
install failed
```

Now, I download the file, but I don't know how to install on my ubuntu?
I have downloaded it from this github: [Image_Graph](https://github.com/pear/Image_Graph)

How can I install it onto my computer?